# Individual Y axis domain in multiple charts in D3

Tags: csv, d3.js, charts

I will create multiple charts from one CSV-file using D3. I want the the Y axis du update in each chart. Now the y axis is the same for all charts. It is set by the maximum value in the whole number1 column, and not for each chart created with d3.nest.

**How can i make the Y axis fit to the number1 data in each chart?**

What is wrong with the code? [JSbin](http://jsbin.com/mocahe/2/edit?js,output)

This is my CSV-data:

```
name,year,number1,number2,number3

Superman,2003,227141296,214978953,212418250 <-- number1 should be max for Superman chart
Superman,2004,232769230,220606887,211301729
Superman,2005,192769230,220606887,211301729
Batman,2003,252873171,239836381,225174161 <-- number1 should be max for Batman chart
Batman,2004,286137492,262439880,243001175
Batman,2004,232769230,220606887,211301729
Spiderman,2006,809584667,279490239,248758932 <-- number1 is now max in every chart
Spiderman,2007,324081833,278022620,246734614
Spiderman,2008,294081833,278022620,246734614
```

Answer (score 0):

I've bumped your bin to [here](http://jsbin.com/bewapiroda/1/edit?js,output).  Essentially, I added three divs and svgs using the `d3.selectAll.data(heroes).enter();`pattern. I then used the `forEach` to add in the axis's and line to each div / svg by passing in each element of the array in the object you created. Note that for some reason, jsbin isn't appending the first of the svg elements.

The `maxNumber` values was then passed to the y-axis constructor inside the foreach loop as were the year / number1 (x/y) values.  The x/y values were passed to a single line generator, instead of the three separate line functions, making things a bit tidier.

Anyhow, hope this helps.